# Как мне протестировать обращение к своим кастомным шаблонам 500 и 403?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я вот такие функции написал, не знаю, как их доделать. Вот такая ошибка NameError: name 'request' is not defined Помогите.

```
def test_urls_correct_template_403(self):
    """Проверка, что страница 403 отдает кастомный шаблон"""
    def permission_denied(request):
        return PermissionDenied

    response = permission_denied(request)
    self.assertEqual(response, 403)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'core/403.html')

def test_urls_correct_template_500(self):
    """Проверка, что страница 500 отдает кастомный шаблон"""
    def server_error(request):
        return HttpResponseServerError()

    response = server_error(request)
    self.assertEqual(response, 500)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'core/500.html')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните вопрос, подскажите, это какой-то фреймворк или Вы делаете всё на чистом Python?

Comment: Да, на чистом python. Это проект сайта на django, осталось протестировать эти два шаблона и сдать проект)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `request` вторым аргументом, чтобы было: `def test_urls_correct_template_403(self, request)` и так во всех 3-х функциях

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете с Flask то

```
from flask import request
```

Comment: Нет, с flask не работаю

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался, не знаю на сколько правильно.

```
def test_urls_correct_template_403(self):
    """Проверка, что страница 403 отдает кастомный шаблон"""
    def server_error():
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    response = server_error()
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

def test_urls_correct_template_500(self):
    """Проверка, что страница 500 отдает кастомный шаблон"""
    def server_error():
        return HttpResponseServerError()
    response = server_error()
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 500)
```